# Orbeon Forms: Set Multiple Radio Button Values via Button

Tags: orbeon

We have many forms that are a checklist of tasks for the maintenance technician to perform, say for an annual motor vehicle inspection. Each tasks has a radio-button for the technician confirm whether the task was completed or not (e.g. ***Done/Not done***, or ***OK/Not OK***, etc) and they are all in the same section on the form.

We want button that calls an Action to default all these radio-buttons in the section to ***OK*** or ***Done*** to speed up the process..

I have tried the following code, but it sets all the ***Done*** values, then the 2nd statement clears the ***Done*** values and sets the ***OK*** values. How can we get it to do both?

```
<xf:action event="DOMActivate">
  <xf:setvalue xxf:iterate="//SubScn2YearlyMaintenance//*[empty(*)]" value="if (//* != '') then 'Done' else ."/>                                             
  <xf:setvalue xxf:iterate="//SubScn2YearlyMaintenance//*[empty(*)]" value="if (//* != '') then 'OK' else ."/>                                        
</xf:action>
```

We know we can set each field individually, but there can be upwards of 50 tasks to perform, and we would want some simple code to set all the Done/OK values if possible.

Example [form](https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/ec1bde1703c19e500509517b30888af3726529c7)

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With something along those lines work for you?

```xml
<xf:action event="DOMActivate">
    <xf:setvalue
        xxf:iterate="
            //SubScn2YearlyMaintenance
            //*[
                empty() and 
                exists(
                    xxf:itemset(concat(local-name(), '-control'), 'xml')
                    //item/value[. = ('checked')]
                )
            ]"
        value="if (// != '') then 'checked' else ."/>
</xf:action>
```

PS: This answer has been updated per OP's feedback.

Comment: Thanks Alex,
We cannot use this code either as the radio-button may not have been populated yet. So the code needs to:
a) Only work for radio-buttons in the section (not any other type of control).
b) Set a Done or OK for each radio-button in that section irrespective of the current value (including blank).

So we need to read the values in each radio-button before setting Done or OK.

Comment: @PeteAtkin I think that (a) is the trickiest. Given an element name in the data, you would like to know if the bound control could allow users to select a value that is either "Done" or "OK". I think you should be able to do this with an expression of the form `exists(xxf:itemset(concat(local-name(), '-control'), 'xml')//item/value[. = ('Done', 'OK')])`, which would go inside the `*[empty(*) and …]`.

Comment: @PeteAtkin Since this most likely won't work a first try (what does?!), I would recommend that you try this on a new form, with just one field with radio buttons. So it is that easier for you to add an `<xf:message>` to the code so you can see what different parts of the XPath expression return, and if you can't figure it out, to put the source of this form in a Gist, which you can share here.

Comment: That's a huge improvement thanks Alex.
Just need to stop it updating text fields too.
The code I used is :

                         <xf:setvalue xxf:iterate="//SubScn2YearlyMaintenance//*[empty(*)and exists(xxf:itemset(concat(local-name(), '-control'), 'xml')//item/value[. = ('checked')])]"
                                                     value="if (//* != '') then 'checked' else ."/>

Comment: FYI - we'd already worked out to put a message at the end of an Action to make sure it gets through all the code thanks

Comment: @PeteAtkin Perfect, I am glad the `xxf:itemset()` helped, and I also updated my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you example I would suggest to use same value same value for every radio button. You can have difference only in label. Then you can use only one `xf:setvalue`.

Second sollution is use same prefix/suffix in name to all radio buttons and use in your XPath funciton `starts-with()` or `ends-with()`.
Result could look like this when rename you OK/Not Ok radio buttons with prefix "OK" :

`<xf:setvalue xxf:iterate="//SubScn2YearlyMaintenance//*[starts-with(name(),'OK') and empty(*)]"`

Comment: And you can try evaluate your XPath in xforms-inspector (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/xforms-inspector). Just add  <fr:xforms-inspector/> after some  </fr:section>

Comment: Thanks Dave, 
Unfortunately we cannot rename the controls as they are part of the existing reporting solution.
Is there a way to only populate those controls that do not already have a value?
PeteA

Comment: Dave,
Unfortunately the Inspector is not available to us in our version..